# iCloud CalDAV response does not return VEVENT Status

Tags: icloud, webdav, caldav

I'm making some requests to retrieve event data from an iCloud calendar.

I need to fetch expanded events by filtering events between a start and end date. So far, so good. However, when retrieving the data from the .ics file, I noticed that the event status is not included, only the participants' statuses.

I have already tried adding the necessary fields in the query, but it's still not being returned.
I need help on how to retrieve the status.

Below is my query:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <C:calendar-query xmlns:D="DAV:"
                     xmlns:C="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav"
                     xmlns:ca="http://apple.com/ns/ical/">
     <D:prop>
       <D:getetag/>
       <C:calendar-data>
         <C:expand start="20230723T030000Z" end="20231023T025959Z"/>
       </C:calendar-data>
     </D:prop>
     <C:filter>
       <C:comp-filter name="VCALENDAR">
         <C:comp-filter name="VEVENT">
           <C:time-range start="20230723T030000Z"
                         end="20231023T025959Z"/>
         </C:comp-filter>
       </C:comp-filter>
     </C:filter>
   </C:calendar-query>
```

I also tried this format, but with no success

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <C:calendar-query xmlns:D="DAV:"
                     xmlns:C="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav">
     <D:prop>
       <D:getetag/>
       <C:calendar-data>
         <C:expand start="20230723T030000Z" end="20231023T025959Z"/>
         <C:comp name="VCALENDAR">
           <C:prop name="VERSION"/>
           <C:comp name="VEVENT">
             <C:prop name="SUMMARY"/>
             <C:prop name="UID"/>
             <C:prop name="DTSTART"/>
             <C:prop name="DTEND"/>
             <C:prop name="DURATION"/>
             <C:prop name="RRULE"/>
             <C:prop name="RDATE"/>
             <C:prop name="EXRULE"/>
             <C:prop name="EXDATE"/>
             <C:prop name="RECURRENCE-ID"/>
             <C:prop name="STATUS"/>
           </C:comp>
           <C:comp name="VTIMEZONE"/>
         </C:comp>
       </C:calendar-data>
     </D:prop>
     <C:filter>
       <C:comp-filter name="VCALENDAR">
         <C:comp-filter name="VEVENT">
           <C:time-range start="20230723T030000Z"
                         end="20231023T025959Z"/>
         </C:comp-filter>
       </C:comp-filter>
     </C:filter>
   </C:calendar-query>
```

Curl request used for this:

```bash
curl -o response.txt -X REPORT -H "Depth: 1" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -H "Authorization: Basic my-token" --data-binary "@query.xml" https://p<number>-caldav.icloud.com/<user-id>/calendars/<calendar-id>
```